# Write program for the following?

Tags: python

My code is trying to create a list of elements of the pascal triangle and then arranging them in the pyramid. But there is some problem I am facing while running the code.

My code:

```
n = int(input())
list1 = []
for i in range (n):
    temp_list = []
    for j in range(i+1):
        if j==0 or j==1:
            temp_list.append(1)
        else:
            temp_list.append(list1[i-1][j-1] + list1[i-1][j])
        list1.append(temp_list)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i-1):
        print(format(" ","<2"),end="")
    for j in range (i+1):
        print(format(list1[i][j],"<3"),end=" ")
    print()
```

What is the mistake in my code? Can anyone rectify it?

Comment: What is your code doing and what is the expectation?

Comment: If some error is occurring, please specify what it is and what line it is occurring on. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The condition j==1 should be j==i.  Also, you want to append temp_list to list1 only at the end of the i-th iteration, not at the end of each j-th iteration also.  So, the append statement should be moved to outside the inner loop (i.e. should be unindented).  This code works:

```
n = int(input())
list1 = []
for i in range (n):
    temp_list = []
    for j in range(i+1):
        if j==0 or j==i:
            temp_list.append(1)
        else:
            temp_list.append(list1[i-1][j-1] + list1[i-1][j])
    list1.append(temp_list)
        
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i-1):
        print(format(" ","<2"),end="")
    for j in range (i+1):
        print(format(list1[i][j],"<3"),end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I list my code as follow, and hope it can help you.

```py
numRows = int(input("please input numRows:"))
ret = list()
for i in range(numRows):
    row = list()
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        if j == 0 or j == i:
            row.append(1)
        else:
            row.append(ret[i - 1][j] + ret[i - 1][j - 1])
    ret.append(row)
print(ret)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thank for your advice, I wrongly thought the few line code is easy to understand. I will include some context to my code in the future.